# Will or going to

Tags: grammar, word-usage

"Stop trying the engine over and over again! It's clear that the car ...."

Won't start or isn't going to start?

Comment: Both are fine, but _isn't gonna_ is the more natural one in that context. _Be going to_ is used to refer to the near future, among other uses.

Comment: @John Lawler You're implying that US cars are more prone to be involved?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Wellll, if we want to get into which ones are less likely to *start*...